# All controls in my app are locked with the left side of the screen

Tags: android, xml

All the textviews and seekbars that I dragged into the android screen in the Android ADK seem to be locked to the left side of the screen by default:
[image]

This is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/freqIndxTextView_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/freqIndxTextView_string" />
    . 
    .
    .
    .
    .
    </LinearLayout>
```

I am supposing the problem is that I have not understood how Linearlayout works. I can move the textviews and seekbars up and down, but their left side seem to be stuck to the left edge of the screen. How do I remove this feature? Is it possible to drag and drop controls on the IDE like we can do in Visual C++?

Comment: Use margin or padding to textview

Comment: You should have look on the relative layout.
and drag and drop controls are possible in IDE but for proper layout you should go with xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use margin in the xml, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/freqIndxTextView_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/freqIndxTextView_string" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is instruction for you. Hope it helps.:)
http://android4beginners.com/2013/07/lesson-2-2-how-to-use-margins-and-paddings-in-android-layout/

Answer (score 1):

Either add padding to the LinearLayout, or change the gravity to center

```
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
```

Or

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 1):

As @QuantumTiger wrote, you can use

android:paddingLeft="16dp"

You can use too

android:margingLeft="16dp"

There is a little difference between them.

Anyway, you can find much more information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html).